# How to turn off need for bitlocker to go on Windows 7

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I am the system administrator of my local computer (Windows 7) and I am unable to write to an external hard drive if it is not encrypted using Bitlocker to go. The local computer is not encrypted and I have searched for a way to turn off the need for encryption, but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4624-bitlocker-drive-encryption-bitlocker-go-turn-off.html seems to have what you need...

Comment: I have turned off encryption on the external hard drive, and decrypted it, but the desktop operating system displays a message stating that I can't write to the external hard drive unless it is encrypted. I don't want to encrypt the hard drive and not sure how to turn off the need for an encrypted external hard drive on the desktop computer.

Comment: The latter half of the document at that link seems to address the turning off process.  Give it a try...

Comment: I can turn off bitlocker to go on the external hard drive, but then when I try to reconnect to the desktop, I can only open it in read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still an open issue, but there are some registry settings that you can set to zero to turn off the read only access to external drives as enforced by BitLocker to go.

The settings can be found in the registry as follows.

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVDenyWriteAccess
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVDenyCrossOrg

I validated that modifying this setting works in the latest release of Windows 10.